# Plug in multiple devices with the exact same IP to one Linux host

Tags: linux, networking, vlan, namespaces

I have a need to have multiple devices with same IP address connected to the same host.

I am attaching a photo to demonstrate the topology

So on the host side the IP is 192.168.**19**.1 and on the 3 devices all have IP of 192.168.**1**.3

I need to supply those 3 devices with tftp ftp and a way to send information to the host

I cannot change the subnet of the host side since i have 3 sets of those 3 devices connected to each linux host.

Can you please help me by advice what is the best solution to implement in such case

illustration: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11fBBB1nNgYYf7vlVg8n-eX2m5sMNLA5P/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Without some significant shenanigans, this isn't possible. Why do the devices have the same IP address? If you provide more details about the overall situation, we might be able to give you a suggestion that isn't completely bonkers.

Comment: Your setup would probably fail as you will ARP poisoning your switch with multiple MAC for the same IP. You would need a HUB, not a switch, in the minimum for your setup, if it work.

Answer (score 1):

Get a couple of small routers. Put different IP's on the WAN interface of each router, and a NAT rule to 192.168.1.3 on the LAN side.